# How can I separate my labels in the x-axis into separate "categories" in my chart?

Tags: javascript

If my question didn't make sense then let me explain.
Basically I am creating a web app for tracking expenses and I want to incorporate a chart to showcase the expenses in a graphical way. I have made three categories which take in separate data, but for some reason when I render the chart it shows all the categories combined as one. (Attachment is provided) [Image of the Bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbSV7.png). From the image provided the categories "MATERIALS", "MAFUTA" and "OTHER" are supposed to be separate but are combined into one hence their data is being added together to create one bar instead of three.

For this reason only the line and bar chart show but the doughnut (which I want) and the pie charts don't work am guessing because of how the labels (categories) are combined into one.

Here is the code for my js file:

```
const renderChart = (data, labels) => {
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Current Month Expenses',
        data: data,
      }]
    },
    options: {
      borderWidth: 10,
      borderRadius: 2,
      hoverBorderWidth: 0,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
      },
    },
  });
}


const getChartData=() => {
  console.log("fetching")
  fetch('expense_category_summary')
      .then((res)=>res.json())
      .then((results)=>{
        console.log("results", results);
        const category_data = results.expense_category_data;
        const [labels, data] = [
            Object.keys(category_data),
            Object.values(category_data),
        ];
        renderChart([data], [labels]);
  });
};
document.onload = getChartData();
```

Comment: Could you share a codepen or codesandbox link?

Comment: Here: https://codepen.io/RAzOR-the-bold/pen/WNLLgQO